# how to calculate the Casimir function of the Heisenberg Lie algebra?

Tags: lie-algebras

Given a Heisenberg Lie algebra of dimension $2n+1$ with generators $X_i$, how can I calculate the Casimir function of the Heiseneberg Lie algebra ?

Comment: I think the usual definition of a Casimir element requires the Lie algebra to be semisimple, no? The Heisenberg algebra is nilpotent, so...

Answer (score 1):

A Casimir operator can also be defined for non-semisimple Lie algebras:

**Definition**: Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a complex Lie algebra und $U(\mathfrak{g})$ be its universal enveloping algebra. An element $C\in U(\mathfrak{g})$ is called *a Casimir operator*, if $[C,X]=0$ for all $X\in U(\mathfrak{g})$. In other words, $C$ is in the center of the universal enveloping algebra.

For the $3$-dimensional Heisenberg Lie algebra, with basis $(e_1,e_2,e_3)$ and $[e_1,e_2]=e_3$, we have that $C=e_3$ is a Casimir operator. The $2n+1$-dimensional Heisenberg can be done similarly, see here:

Reference: [Casimir operators for non-semisimple Lie algebras](https://www.matrix-inst.org.au/wp_Matrix2016/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Isaac_July_2017.pdf).

Comment: thank you Dietrich Burde . I find a reference that gives the Casimir function for the 3-dimensional  Heisenberg Lie algebra is C = x + y and the Casimir function  for the 2n+1-dimensional  Heisenberg Lie algebra is  Ci=xi+yi .

Comment: Reference: https://ejpam.com/index.php/ejpam/article/viewFile/1515/278

Comment: see the end of this article and in the references

Comment: I am looking for how does the calculation to find  C= x+y and Ci = xi+yi

Comment: No idea why they call them Casimir operators... these are not operators by the way. Maybe because it looks more fashionable than "central elements of the universal enveloping algebra"?

Comment: @YCor Several words are in use, Casimir element, Casimir operator, Casimir invariant, see for example the German [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casimir-Operator) page.

Comment: @YCor They are called operators because there is an isomorphism between the universal enveloping algebra and the left-invariant differential operators on the corresponding Lie group.