# Centre of universal enveloping algebra

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory

Take $\mathfrak{g}$ a simple complex Lie algebra and $U(\mathfrak{g})$ its universal enveloping algebra and $Z(\mathfrak{g})$ the center of this last one. From universal property of the universal enveloping algebra we know that the category of $\mathfrak{g}$-modules is equivalent to the category of $U(\mathfrak{g})$-modules. My question are three:

> Is it true that, since character theory, two irreducible representation of $\mathfrak{g}$  is determined by action of $Z(\mathfrak{g})$ and not all $U(\mathfrak{g})$ when $\mathfrak{g}$ is finite dimensional?

> I read often that the center $Z(\mathfrak{g})$ is important for knowing representation theory of $\mathfrak{g}$, is for the precedent reason?

Comment: Ok, right. I edited the question

Comment: Just to give an example, how various the results can be, have a look at [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9905128.pdf) for example, i.e., Kostant suggested the Whittaker model of the center of the universal enveloping algebra ...

Comment: And [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3087686/how-to-calculate-the-casimir-function-of-the-heisenberg-lie-algebra?noredirect=1&lq=1) for Casimir operators and the center of the universal enveloping algebra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second question is (possibly accidentally) incredibly broad. Yes, the center of the universal enveloping algebra is very important in many aspects of representation theory...

For your first question, I believe Harish-Chandra proved that, for a given character of the center of the universal enveloping algebra, there are only *finitely_many* irreducible $\mathfrak g,K$-modules with that character. In very small cases, there may be just a single one, but not more generally (though I do not immediately know a counter-example).

At the very least, technical reasons will always make the *center* of a non-commutative ring be significant, if it's non-trivial (think of Schur's lemma). And the universal enveloping algebra of a Lie algebra is important because it is an *associative* algebra with the same representation theory as the original Lie algebra.

Comment: Thank you, it has been useful. Could I ask for some references about the (maybe) Harish-Chandra theorem which you are talking about?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have a precise recollection of _which_ paper where the result occurred...